# How to add scroll-bar in the chart

Tags: angularjs, charts, angular-chart

Hi I have created a sample chart using public data, but it has more data to display in the chart, so I'm trying to add scroll-bar along x-axis so that all the data are displayed neatly. But I'm finding it difficult to add the scroll-bar to x-axis, so how to add scroll-bar to the chart. I have attached a plnkr for viewing. Please help me.Thank you :)

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('app',["chart.js"]);
myApp.controller("chartController",function($scope,$http){
$scope.totalDocks = [];
$scope.availDocks =[];
 $http.get("http://citibikenyc.com/stations/json")
.then(function(item){
    var dataFetched = item;
    console.log(dataFetched.data.stationBeanList[0]);
       for(var i=0; i < 100 ; i++){              
                   $scope.totalDocks.push(dataFetched.data.stationBeanList[i].totalDocks);
          $scope.availDocks.push(dataFetched.data.stationBeanList[i].availableDocks);
       }
 })
})
```

[Plunker File](http://plnkr.co/edit/nfvmy84cl83CHJkZNUpy?p=info)

Comment: I do not think you can add a scroll bar, instead you can skip the points and display some pattern

Comment: Can make it clear.

Comment: did it help with what you wanted to achieve?

Comment: Still the x-axis data are clustered and everything is overlapped :(

Comment: did you check the demo

Comment: I think you have posted the wrong plnkr... Becoz my plnkr anr your's look the same...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135512/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-sree).

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/fyQP1VFcvfp8deeh5ocm?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Since angular.chart is responsive by itself, you do not have to add scroll bar manually, instead inorder to make chart to appear claerly you can make ticks along x axis to be skipped.

Add this to your options config,

```
 $scope.options = {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          autoSkipPadding: 100
        }
      }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true

  };
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/fyQP1VFcvfp8deeh5ocm?p=preview)**